# Excel 2010 VBA: Consolidating data from tables in closed workbooks: Copy/Paste or Array?

Tags: arrays, excel, listobject, consolidation

I've got a macro to consolidate data from 2 different tables in 14 different workbooks, tblstaff and tblwage.  Currently, the way the code works is:

- Open source WB
- copy ListObject.DataBodyRange from each
- PasteSpecial (xlvalues) into consolidated ListObject.DataBodyRange
- Close source WB
- Next Source WB

**My question:** Is this the most efficient way to go about doing this? I'm not very familiar with arrays in VBA, but was wondering if I could accomplish the same by creating two 2d arrays (staff and wage) and reading each table into them, pasting the final/consolidated array at the end of the loop.  Thanks in advance!

Edit: Assuming arrays are more efficient here, how do I go about creating and ReDim'ing the 2d array, reading each new table into it? Probably safe to say there's errors with the below:

```
Set MarRange = WBMaster.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("marcirc,mar8a")
arraysize = 0
ReDim myArray(0 To 0)

For Each MarCell In MarRange

marfile = WBMaster.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("mardir").Value & MarCell.Value
Application.StatusBar = "Importing data from " & marfile
Workbooks.Open marfile, True, True
Set WBMar = ActiveWorkbook

ReDim Preserve myArray(arraysize) As Variant
myArray = WBMar.Sheets("Staffing Details").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value
arraysize = arraysize + 1

Next MarCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - any tips on how to go about it? Added code sample in original question.

Comment: I don't think you will gain much from using arrays in this example. You could use the PowerQuery add-in to pull in the data?